# Install extension using composer Magento 2

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm using magento 2 , and I'm trying to install an extension from  composer.json file , now I've installed composer through SSH , but I'm new to composer installations , how do I proceed now with the installation ?

Comment: Is it the extension on a public or private composer repository?

Comment: I think is public , not sure about that , as I told you I'm new to composer , by the way this is the extension https://marketplace.magento.com/addshoppers-social-login.html

Comment: what is the file location when you install it through composer

Answer (score 12):

Follow below steps to install magento2 extension (2.1.7)

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
composer require <component-name>:<version> --no-update
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/howtos/install-components.html

Answer (score 6):

For Composer installation see here [official Site of composer.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)
After installation it, You can install Magento 2 extensions with Composer: add an extension's package to the root `composer.json` and then do `composer update` and `bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Now clear the cache `bin/magento cache:clean`.

Done!

Comment: but in my root folder there is already a composer.json , is not that gonna affect in any way ?

Comment: You can make a backup copy of `composer.json` first. Use the command `composer require <module name>`, where `<module name>` is located in `<sample module root dir>/etc/module.xml` as the value of `module name=`. That updates `composer.json` so all you have to do is run `composer update` to install it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the sample how to install the [Adm Developer Toolbar](https://github.com/vpietri/magento2-developer-quickdevbar) using the composer.

```
composer require vpietri/adm-quickdevbar &&
php bin/magento --clear-static-content module:enable ADM_QuickDevBar && 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```